# VB MS Word: Bind XML into an ordered lists?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

Is there any way to bind ordered lists to XML documents in MS Word?

Currently I have xml such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myvars>
  <name>foo</name>
</myvars>
```

Then I load and map it to a contentcontrol:

```
ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add
ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts(5).Load ("c:\test.xml") 

Dim strXPath1 As String
strXPath1 = "/myvars/name"
ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).XMLMapping.SetMapping strXPath1
```

However this is only useful for single texts. Is there anyway to map xml enteries to ordered lists? For example:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <myvars>
      <person>
         <name>foo</name>
         <alias>bar</alias>
         <alias>chew</alias>
      </person>             
      <person>
         <name>alpha</name>
         <alias>bravo</alias>
         <alias>charlie</alias>
      </person>             
    </myvars>
```

mapped into the word document so that it shows up as ordered lists:

```
1.   foo
     a. bar
     b. chew
2.   alpha
     a. bravo
     b. charlie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the answer is you cannot. You can only map simple text and combo box type content controls to XML.